# Unittesting some function comprising instance of some class with pytest

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, oop, pytest

Consider the module `some_module.py` with the following content (in my actual use case, `SomeClass` and `some_function` are defined in separate modules):

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.some_attr = v

    def some_method(self):
        self.some_attr += self.some_attr


def some_function(val):
    c = SomeClass(val)
    c.some_method()
    return c
```

Assume that I have already unittested `SomeClass` using [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/). Now I want to unittest `some_function`. My understanding is that I should mock everything related to `SomeClass`. What I tried was to add the following test function to `some_module.py`:

```
def test_some_function(mocker):
    # arrange
    c = mocker.MagicMock()
    c.some_attr = 10

    mocker.patch('some_module.SomeClass', return_value=c)
    mocker.patch('some_module.SomeClass.some_method')
    
    # act
    c = some_function(10)

    # assert
    assert c.some_attr == 20
```

Running `pytest some_module.py` in a terminal (obviously) results in failure of the test as `c.some_attr` is 10. What should the test function look like instead?

Comment: "My understanding is that I should mock everything related to SomeClass." Why is that?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, given Laurent's answer, I think the definition of unittesting which I had in mind was just wrong (not the one you have in mind?). Do you support the approach of not mocking if the burden is not too big as suggested here, for example: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/382092

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, since `SomeClass` has already been tested successfully and since the purpose of `some_function` seems to simply be to return an instance of `SomeClass` for which `some_method` has been called once and only once, there's no point in mocking it (and it is preferable to [avoid mocks](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/376783) when possible).

Therefore, I suggest you test `some_function` like this:

```py
from some_module import SomeClass, some_function


def test_some_function():

    c = some_function(10)
    assert isinstance(c, SomeClass)
    assert c.some_attr == 20

    c = some_function(-10)
    assert isinstance(c, SomeClass)
    assert c.some_attr == -20

    c = some_function(0)
    assert isinstance(c, SomeClass)
    assert c.some_attr == 0
```

Comment: Thank you, @Laurent, I guess I need to change the definition of unittesting in my head.